# Connection error, connect from Visual Studio 2010 to SQL Server 2008 with ip, port

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using a program written with Visual Studio to connect to a remote SQL Server instance on a domain (Windows Server 2008). Domain administrator doesn't allow using Windows authentication system for SQL Server. When I use SQL Server authentication, I get this error

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=[ip],1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=[db];Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=sa; Password=[pass];MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

When I use Management Studio on my system (client) I can connect to database on server with SQL Server authentication.

I also tried to connect to local database with ip, port with this connection string

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=[db];Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=sa; Password=[pass];MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

I got the same error.

Note: I already add inbound rule for port 1433. OTOH on domain server with firewall off nothing is better.

When searching on the web for a solution, I reached the `setspn` command, but if I'm true, it is used in windows authenticate mode.

Now, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **remove** the `Integrated Security=SSPI;` from your connection string (that's saying: *use Windows Authentication*).

```
Data Source=[ip],1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=[db];User ID=sa; Password=[pass];MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

If you have both the `Integrated Security=` and an explicit user/password in your connection string, the integrated security *wins* - remove it, and you should be good.

PS: I would **strongly recommend** to ***NEVER*** use the `sa` account - not even in development and testing!